# Word 2010 freezing after typing a few characters

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

I have a weird problem with Word 2010 on Windows 7. After typing a few characters, the program just stops responding. Sometimes it becomes responsive again, but most of the time it doesn't.

I tried deleting temporary files and also deleting an orphaned default template file (something like ~normal.dot), which did not have any effect. I have no idea where to start troubleshooting this problem, other than reinstalling Windows, which I'd rather avoid.

Edit: the problem persist in safe mode. The event log shows activity of the Office Software Protection Platform Service.

Comment: Does it also freeze when you start winword in safe mode? (`Winword.exe /a`)

Comment: If you check CPU and memory utilization with the Task Manager, which you can run by hitting Ctrl-Alt-Del and selecting Task Manager or by clicking on the Windows Start button and typing taskmgr in the "Search programs and files" field, by clicking on the Processes tab in Task Manager what do you see for the CPU and memory utilization for WINWORD.EXE when Word becomes unresponsive? You can put the process list in alphabetical order by clicking on the "Image Name" column header. Is the CPU utilization for Word high or does it stay at zero when Word becomes unresponsive?